# php socket flow error 10054. How to resolve it?

Tags: php, ssh, websocket

I'm using a php socket server on vps host. Whenever I connect the php server it times out in 15 to 20 min with

> Reason:FlowSocketReader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Move to a different provider